# Issue with FK being null in EF

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, foreign-keys

I have two entities namely Idea and Reaction

Topic:

```
public class Idea
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimePosted { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Reaction> Reactions { get; set; }
    }
```

Reaction:

```
public class Reaction
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimePosted { get; set; }
        public Reaction Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

The SQLite db generated fine without having to do any tweaking in the OnModelCreating in my DbContext, as my Reaction had a column for `IdeaId` and `ParentId`. But when I want to add my reaction to the topic, the FK never seems to be filled in.

This is how I attempt to add it:

```
public void AddIdeaReaction(string id, string reactionText)
        {
            Idea idea = _ideaRepo.GetById(id);
            Reaction reaction = new Reaction()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                TimePosted = DateTime.Now,
                Text = reactionText
            };

            _reactionRepo.Create(reaction);
            idea.Reactions.Add(reaction);
            UpdateIdea(idea);
        }
```

The reaction gets added to the table, but the FK to the IdeaId stays NULL.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
The problem was that I set the ChangeTracker's autotracking to false.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `IdeaId` in your `Reaction` table

```
public class Reaction
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimePosted { get; set; }
    public Reaction Parent { get; set; }
    public int IdeaId { get; set; }
}
```

Like this EF is able to identify how data is related when you Create or Update the entity

Sorry for my english.

Comment: But EF adds the IdeaId in the database for me?
And i've been trying it out in another test project with only this scenario and there it works fine

Comment: But EF adds the IdeaId in the database for me? --> Yes its suppossed to do it that's fluent API mode, EF detects the relationships automatically without specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to tell EF about the relationship either via OnModelCreating or a Configuration.  EF can fill in some blanks via convention, but honestly I don't count on it and just use explicit mappings because then I'm sure it's associating things the way I expect it to.

```
// ** EF6 **
public class IdeaConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Idea>
{
    public IdeaConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Ideas");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        HasMany(x => x.Reactions)
            .WithRequired()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("IdeaId")); // This tells EF to use an IdeaId field on Reaction.
    }
}

// ** EF Core **
    public class IdeaConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Idea>
    {
        void IEntityTypeConfiguration<Idea>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Idea> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Ideas");
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder.HasMany(x => x.Reactions)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey("IdeaId"); // Creates a shadow property for the association.
        }
    }
```

This may also be possible with attributes. IMO explicit configuration simply leaves fewer mysteries to waste time. :)